# GCP cloud function - how to read a local file in .net6

Tags: google-cloud-platform, .net-core, google-cloud-functions

I am migrating the cloud function from node to dotnet6. In node, I am able to read local files but I am getting errors in donet6

here is my function structure -

```
Function.cs
Sample.csproj
EmailOrderCompleteGL.html
```

runtime": "dotnet6"

Different Code that I tried -

**#1 -**

```
string filePath = "./EmailOrderCompleteGL.html";
  string htmlContent = "";
  using (System.IO.StreamReader reader=new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath)) 
  {
      htmlContent=reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
 Console.WriteLine($"htmlContent  {htmlContent}");
```

**#2 -**

```
  string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\EmailOrderCompleteGL.html");

            Console.WriteLine("Your file content is:");
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("./EmailOrderCompleteGL.html"))
            {
                string s = "";
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
```

**#3 -**

```
string path = @"./EmailOrderCompleteGL.html";
        StreamReader sreamReader = new StreamReader(path);
        htmlContent = sreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine($"sreamReader  {htmlContent}");
```

Error -

```
"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/layers/google.dotnet.publish/publish/bin/EmailOrderCompleteGL.html'.
File name: '/layers/google.dotnet.publish/publish/bin/EmailOrderCompleteGL.html'
   at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategy(FileStream fileStream, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that your project file doesn't specify that the HTML file needs to be copied to the output directory.

As an aside, I'd recommend `File.ReadAllText` as a simpler way of reading all the content.

Here's a sample project file which *does* work, along with a complete function:

DisplayHtml.csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Functions.Hosting" Version="2.0.0" />
    <None Include="appsettings*.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
    <!--
      - This is the line I suspect you're missing.
      - You could specify individual files if you'd prefer.
      -->
    <None Include="*.html" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Function.cs:

```cs
using Google.Cloud.Functions.Framework;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DisplayHtml;

public class Function : IHttpFunction
{
    public async Task HandleAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        string html = File.ReadAllText("Test.html");
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(html);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did this mistake. Thanks for the quick reply.